# Как сменить кодировку текста в базе данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных, utf-8

Изначально в базе была кодировка в каком то latin вроде и в тексте крякозябры вместо букв.

После выполнения данной команды кодировка текста в базе не меняется, хотя кодировка таблицы изменилась.

```
ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

В базе вот такая фигня

Øàìàíñêàÿ âûñòàâêà «Çâóêè Âåðõíåãî Ìèðà»

Никакие решения которые находятся не помогают.

Какие еще есть варианты исправить это?

Comment: Ну, довольно логично, что если в базу было записано именно Øàìàíñêàÿ, то при любых конвертированиях туда-сюда база будет стараться максимально сохранить это самое Øàìàíñêàÿ в первозданном виде

Comment: UPDATE таблицы с явной конвертацией. Однако если выполнено изменение кодировки таблицы/поля, скорее всего часть данных будет повреждена. Надо было, не трогая поля, создать новое поле с нужной кодировкой, и скопировать туда данные с соотв. конвертацией.